# Custom stopWords Lucene 4.0

Tags: java, lucene, words

I'm trying to add my own stopWord list at Lucene 4.0 but I believe its not working at all since its not changing the search results.

Thats what I'm doing:

```
CharArraySet stopWords = new CharArraySet(Version.LUCENE_40, 100, true);
stopWords.add("lot");
stopWords.add("of");
stopWords.add("words");
stopWords.add("added");
stopWords.add("here");

BrazilianAnalyzer analyzer = new BrazilianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40, stopWords);
```

Is there anything I'm missing?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using this for indexing, searching, or both?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't changing the search results?  You will still see stopwords in the stored documents in the index.  You should not find results on stop words when searching.  How, exactly, is what you are seeing different from your expectations?

Comment: I'm using this for searching, maybe that's the reason? 
The analyzer I build with this stopWord list is just in my searching class.

And when I said I was expecting different results, I meant by using my stopWords list instead of the default stopWord list.
Ex: Using default stopWord list I had the results A, B and C. 
But with my stopWord list I was expecting it to be C, A and B.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same results but in a different order, I would check the scoring of the document hits -- I don't think Lucene guarantees anything about hit order if the hits score the same. ([Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) could be helpful here.)